# Get and store multidimensional array not JSON in Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, cloud, firebase

I am using multidimensional array (not JSON) in Javascript.

```
var Ar = [
 ['1','2013','A','Name1','1','1','3','3','1','2','3','4',''],
 ['2','2014','B','Name2','1','2','3','1','1','2','3','5',''],
 ['3','2015','C','Name3','1','2','4','4','1','2','5','4','']
];
```

To send or store Array **Ar** to **Firebase** Cloud I use:

```
var data = new Firebase("xxxx.firebaseIO.com");
data.set(Ar);
```

I use this 2D array form a lot.

What option do I have to get or store individual data or array back from Firebase Cloud?

1. Like refresh and sync Array **Ar** with the Cloud
2. Store new data the cloud **Ar[2][3] = "New Text"**
3. Get value from the cloud **var x = Ar[2][3]**

Hope you can help

Thanks K

Comment: What problem do you have? Also: did you read the Firebase documentation, specifically the section about why arrays are often a bad idea in distributed systems (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push)?

Comment: I was aware of how this basic JSON structure idea is in Firebase. Sometimes you have already well defined array. As you can see, I was sending the whole array with one simple command **data.set(Ar);** to the cloud. Why can I not have another command to do the opposite or pull all those information back? I also noticed Firebase will automatically put index number on each idem in the array. Indexing array is very fast and effective way of getting data. By giving all data name you need to do complex name search instead of giving just a simple index number which is always fixed like **x=Ar[2][3]**

Comment: Cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/kIRHq2WfFLM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = [
 ['1','2013','A','Name1','1','1','3','3','1','2','3','4',''],
 ['2','2014','B','Name2','1','2','3','1','1','2','3','5',''],
 ['3','2015','C','Name3','1','2','4','4','1','2','5','4','']
];

var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/');

ref.set(array);

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var value = snapshot.val();

  console.log(value);  
  console.log(value[2][3]);
});
```

The output from the above is:

```
[["1", "2013", "A", "Name1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "2", "3", "4", ""], 
 ["2", "2014", "B", "Name2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "2", "3", "5", ""], 
 ["3", "2015", "C", "Name3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "1", "2", "5", "4", ""]]
"Name3"
```

Any time any part of the array changes, the value event will fire again and the `on('value'` callback will be invoked.

If you want to update the array, you have two options.

```
array[2][3] = "New Text";
ref.set(array);
```

This will send the entire array to Firebase. The alternative is to update the one the element at [2][3] straight in your database:

```
ref.child(2).child(3).set("Newest Text");
```

No matter which of the two approaches you use, the `on('value'` callback will be invoked again.

Check out this jsbin for a working version of the code: http://jsbin.com/nawatetuya/edit?js,console

Comment: This was great and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot Frank

Answer (score 2):

This can be answered in the [Angular Firebase API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) if you're using Angular.

Look for `$save` and `$add` to save and add data to Firebase. To get values from the database, you just have to assign a variable like

`var obj = $firebaseObject(ref);`

and you can get the data from the variable to the DOM like

`$scope.data = obj;`

Pretty simple.

You can manipulate the data before it reaches the DOM inside a factory or service first then use a controller to get or present information.